# Using a specific version of Buffer in Webpack

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

My project depends on `buffer` ^4.0.0, but Webpack (through `node-libs-browser`) uses ^3.0.0. Updating the `buffer` dependency in `node-libs-browser` breaks `crypto-browserify`, so a PR would be require a lot more effort. What is the best way of overriding this module provided by node-libs-browser?

I attempted to use the `resolve.alias` configuration option with no success whatsoever. I installed the latest `buffer` as a project dependency, and I attempted the following:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    buffer: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/buffer')
  }
}
```

I also tried using `'buffer$'`, `'Buffer$'`, and `Buffer` for the key, and this had no effect (didn't want to leave anything up to chance). I even tried ResolverPlugin and ProvidePlugin, but had no success.

My project still ends up using `node-libs-browser`'s Buffer, and I'm struggling to understand why.